# Java get subject key identifier from certificate X509Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate

I have p7b-file with some certificate inside, I open it in Java and get Subject with this code:

```
 try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.p7b")) {
       final CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
       certificateFactory.generateCertificates(inputStream).forEach(certificate -> {
           final X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificate;
           System.out.println("subjectDN: " + x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().getName());   
           
                System.out.println("__" + x509Certificate.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.14").hashCode() );
        
           System.out.println("*************************");
       });
   }
```

It's work fine, but I need to get Subject Key Identifier like this:

[image]

and it must be only on free Java without bouncycastle or any other framework. Please help, how to do it? Thanks!